# Can I have custom tab leaders in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

When creating a tab you have the option to select from a few leaders. One of them is the dots leader. However, I want to have a dots leader with spaces:
`. . . . . .` instead of `.............`.

Is this possible? I can't find anything that discusses this.

Answer (score 2):

With help of a friend, I got to a solution using font spacing on the dots. 
It's more of a hack I suppose, but it works fine.

Here is how to do it:

When creating a tab stop, put it on the regular dots. Then select the entire block of dots and go to font options.

In Word 2013, under the advanced section there is "Spacing". Put it on "Expanded" and put "By" on 2 pt (or however big you want the spacing).

[image: Font spacing]